# Controlling the ESC key action in a JavaFX dialog

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX application which will initially show a Login dialog for user to key in user name and password. See below source codes.

If the user clicks on the "Connect" button, the application will perform the login with the entered user name and password, hides the Login dialog, and then shows the main window.

If the user clicks on the "Exit" button or the "X" close button, an alert will be shown to get the user's confirmation. If the user confirms, the application exits.

My problem is what happens when the user press the Escape key when the Login dialog is showing. When this key is pressed, the exit confirmation alert will be shown and immediately after that it will be closed. So what we see is the exit confirmation dialog showing up momentarily whenever the Escape key is pressed.

Why is this happening?

I want pressing the Escape key to be equivalent to clicking on the "Exit" or "X" button. That is, when Escape key is pressed, the exit confirmation dialog is shown.

Alternatively, is it possible to disable the Escape key altogether?

Thanks in advance.

```
public class TestApp extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        this.primaryStage = stage;
        HBox pane = new HBox();
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        showLoginDialog();
    }

    public void showLoginDialog() {
        Dialog<String> loginDialog = new Dialog<>();
        loginDialog.setTitle("Login");
        loginDialog.setHeaderText("Enter User Name and Password to login.");
        loginDialog.setResizable(false);
        Label userNameLabel = new Label("User Name:");
        Label passwordLabel = new Label("Password:");
        TextField userNameField = new TextField();
        userNameField.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        PasswordField passwordField = new PasswordField();
        passwordField.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 35, 20, 35));
        grid.add(userNameLabel, 1, 1);
        grid.add(userNameField, 2, 1);
        grid.add(passwordLabel, 1, 2);
        grid.add(passwordField, 2, 2);
        loginDialog.getDialogPane().setContent(grid);
        loginDialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);
        loginDialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CANCEL);
        Button connectButton = (Button) loginDialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK);
        connectButton.setText("Connect");
        connectButton.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, event -> {
            // perform login here
            loginDialog.hide();
            primaryStage.show();
            event.consume();
        });
        Button exitButton = (Button) loginDialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.CANCEL);
        exitButton.setText("Exit");
        exitButton.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, event -> {            
            handleExit();
            event.consume();
        });
        Stage stage = (Stage) loginDialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
            handleExit();
            event.consume();
        });
        stage.show();
    }

    private void handleExit() {
        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "", ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
        alert.setHeaderText("Confirm exit?");
        alert.resultProperty().addListener((observable, previous, current) -> {
            if (current == ButtonType.YES) {
                System.exit(1);
            }
        });
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: The code above works fine for me. The escape button just shows the confirmation dialog and nothing more.

Comment: When I press the escape key, the confirmation alert shows up and then immediately closes.

Comment: That doen't happened for me. Very strange... are you sure you are running tha code above? What is your jdk version?

Comment: I'm using JFK1.8.

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked for me also.

Comment: Also `System.exit(1)` is not the recommended way to end a `JavaFX` program. Try `Platform.exit()`.

Comment: Sorry for not replying earlier as I was sick and away from my computer. The above codes are indeed exactly what I tested with. When I pressed and released the ESC key on the Login dialog, the exit confirmation alert will be shown and then immediately disappear.

Answer (score 0):

See if this makes a difference:

```
private void handleExit() {
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "", ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
    alert.setHeaderText("Confirm exit?");

    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
    if(result.get() == ButtonType.YES)
    {
         Platform.exit();
    }

    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: I substituted my handleExit() method with yours. And what happens now is this: when I press and and release the ESC key, the confirmation alert will appear, disappear, and then appear again.

Comment: In your handleExit() method, I put a System.out.println("XX"); before the alert.show(). Then when the application is run, I press and release the ESC button on the Login dialog. And the "XX" is printed! This means that the alert.showAndWait() does not block at all! Very strange!

Comment: You definitely have something strange going on. I would update Java and my IDE.

Comment: My JDK version is 1.8.0_66. I am using Eclipse Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) Build id: 20170314-1500. What are yours?

Comment: Looks like this is a bug. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8131151